# What is this dirt like substance coming out of my garage walls? It keeps coming back after I sweep it up

Tags: walls, garage

When I bang on the walls more of the stuff keeps dropping too. Is the gap between the concrete and dry wall suppose to be sealed? House was built in 2007.

[image]

[image]

Other side of the wall

[image]

Comment: What does the outside look like?  Would think there might be a hole/opening that is allowing dirt and leaves to get inside the wall.

Comment: If the leaves are coming from the wall my first thought is that they are nesting material for things that bring them in.

Comment: This is the other side of the wall https://imgur.com/a/Q73Ze20. Not sure why there is a huge gap there.

Comment: I don't see any light from the outside, the leaves might be from when the times I left the garage open on windy days and some leaves blew into the garage

Comment: The gap might be from the ground being very dry.  Are you in drought conditions?

Comment: I don't think so, I live in Houston area, its humid most of the year. This summer was brutal though.

Comment: Any chance it is from ants building a nest there?

Comment: Is the interior cement floor below the level of the outside turf?

Comment: Fine dirt: ants. Leaves and fluff (e.g., chewed paper), rodents

Answer (score 2):

This sort of mess can come from ants or termites inside the wall.

Comment: Yep, could be frass.

Comment: So ants are basically eating my house to the ground? Do you know if an exterminator can do both or do I need a seperate contractor to first remove the drywall then call exterminator?